# Jquery addClass with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a basic menu like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
</ul>
```

How can I add the class "current" for each one of my `<li>` elements every 800 ms, and of course delete the old current element?

Comment: Read up on JS timers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll loop forever through any number of list items:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $lis = $("li"), i = -1;
    function nextCurrent() {
        $lis.eq(i).removeClass("current");
        $lis.eq(i=(i+1)%$lis.length).addClass("current");
        setTimeout(nextCurrent, 800);
    }
    nextCurrent();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/4skLV/

And may I suggest that before you next post a question you read this article: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @loloMinou, then accept it, (or other answer which is better or write your own answer if you can answer it better than the provided answer) with the check sign on the left of the desired answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li').each(function(i){
    var $that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $that.addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
    }, i *800);
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5eZaY/)

Comment: I answered though you didn't show any research effort just for the fun  of the challenge, I'm not sure it's wise though...

Comment: I'd give you an upvote, but then I'll never catch up to your reputation. (Just kidding, +1 to you for your effort when really the OP didn't deserve it - though I went ahead and posted my own version just for the fun of it too...)